# Replace div with relative id via PHP

Tags: php, html

There is HTML:

```
<div id="attachment_21727" class="someclass">
  <img alt="text" src="url" />
  <p class="wp-caption-text">Text</p>
</div>
```

I need to replace `div` to another tag. So i need to find this `div`,find content in it, and replace.

```
attachment_21727 - relative as attachment_{number}
```

So i have a function PHP:

```
$pattern = "/<div id=\"attachment_(.*?)\" (.*?)>(.*?)<\/div>/i";
$replacement = '<figure>$3</figure>';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

But not working...Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use JS for it. It makes it a lot easier

Comment: SuperDJ, I'm creating XML. I need PHP

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your regex like below:-

```
#<div id=\"attachment_(.*?)\">(.+?)</div>#s
```

Working snippet:-

```
<?php

$content = '<div id="attachment_21727" class="someclass">
  <img alt="text" src="url" />
  <p class="wp-caption-text">Text</p>
</div>';

$pattern = "#<div id=\"attachment_(.*?)\">(.+?)</div>#s";



$replacement = '<figure>$2</figure>';

echo $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/990377

Comment: Was about to write an answer but saw this one.  To explain what the difference is, the "s" flag in the regex ensures the "." represents any character including newlines.  By default it matches any character except newlines.

Comment: @Zhurka  glad to help you :):)